# How to make Jasper Report on ZK framework java with MCV approach with ireport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, zk

Basically, I am working on ZK but not to solve this problem. I want to show Jasper report on a page with ZK, not using Jasper viewer. Kindly help me out, please.

I have this code but this is showing jasper report on Jasper viewer but I need it on a web browser by using ZK framework.

code:

```
String source="/periodRep.jrxml";
InputStream is=Jasper.class.getResourceAsStream(source);
JasperReport rep=JasperCompileManager.compileReport(is);
JasperPrint jp=JasperFillManager.fillReport(rep, null,var.conn);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jp);
JasperViewer jv=new JasperViewer(jp,false);
jv.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get a byte array from exportReportToPdf.

Based on this link: http://java91.blogspot.de/2014/05/how-to-read-pdf-in-zk.html

Make an AMedia object out of the byte[].

remove:

```
JasperViewer jv=new JasperViewer(jp,false);
jv.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thanks alot Dennis G. for your reply. I will follow it soon.

Comment: I would be interested to know if the proposed solution was helpful.